# Proper DB setup - too many joins?

Tags: mysql, join

I am setting up a database where I have movies, directors, camera operator, composer of score etc.

Now for each movie there is a row with title, description etc. Also, there should be a column for the director, composer and so forth.

I do not want to repeat the name of a director for every row in the film table, so I put the directors in a different table, the composers in a different table and so on.

In the film table, I then reference with a foreign key to to data of the director, composer etc.

To get ALL data of a movie, I would create a view where I join all the tables together so that a single MySQL query would give me the human readable information of a movie.

Is this a good way to do this? Or are several left joins not a good idea?

The view would look like this (kindof)

```
SELECT `movies`.`title` as `title`, `movies`.`description` as [...],
`directors`.`name` as `name` [...], `composers`.`name` as `cname` [...]
from
    `movies`
left join
    `directors` on `movies`.`directors_id`=`directors`.`id`
left join
    `movies`.`musicians_id` = `musicians`.`id` [...]
```

Would that be an efficient way to do it?

Comment: Your method is called *normalization* and it is a good way of storing the data.

Comment: Your approach is perfectly fine. You might want to replace the LEFT JOINs with INNER JOINs where appropriate (I guess every move has a director, for example).

Comment: I still do not really understand the difference between inner and left joins (and I know the picture with the circles. Need to get my head around it more, I believe). Thanks for the quick answers!

Comment: I get the felling you are reinventing the wheel: there are many movie databases out there My tip for success with software: if you can buy it, don't build it.

Comment: @onedaywhen: There could be a million reasons why I build this database. Maybe I am concentrating only about movies of people who do not answer questions but give their "wisdom" instead. But let me tell you: I do not intend to do a movie page, honestly. It was an example so I did not need to tell what I am really about to do.

Comment: @ArminHierstetter: you must be a clever person because you figured out the Principle of Full Normalization all on your own ...but you did have to resort to a Q&A site to verify your understanding. This is an effective way for you to get things done but isn't necessarily very efficient. Try reading a book; anything by C J Date is good. That's my answer :) Sincere good luck.

Comment: @onedaywhen I am not *that* smart. I knew the concept of normalization before. I am not a MySQL wizard, but I am familiar with the basic stuff. The reason for my question was: I was not sure whether there was a more elegant query technique instead of joining all those tables together. As I am just setting up this database I wanted to make sure, the foundation is right.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by Gordon Linoff, this is called normalization and *in general* is a good way of storing the data.

You certainly need LEFT joins in your way of defining the tables. If a LEFT join is replaced with INNER JOIN, then there will be no row at all in the result for a movie that has no musician or no director.

However, your proposed normalization will end up with many tables for the different creative roles in the film industry. Even to cover the major creative roles for which there are Oscars and other awards, you will need ten or more tables.

A common way to avoid this is to have a single table for movies and a single table for creatives. A third table is used to connect the two in different roles. For example:

```
TABLE CREATIVE_ROLES_LINK ( LIKN_ID INT, MOVIE_ID INT, ROLE_NAME VARCHAR(30), PERSON_ID INT);
```

The above shows the basic idea. In practice, even more normalization can be done with ROLE_NAME stored in another table.

Comment: "normalization in general is a good way of storing the data" -- now there's an understatement!

Comment: Not an "understatement" when data is nowadays as likely to be stored in document and key-value databases as in SQL tables.